# Переход с ide на virtio не даёт прироста скорости на некоторых виртуальных машинах

Tags: proxmox

*Proxmox*. Заменил на некоторых *ВМ* виртуальные жёсткие диски  с *IDE* на *VirtIO*.

В файлах `/etc/pve/qemu-server/*.conf` заменил вот такие строки: `bootdisk: virtio0` вместо `ide0`:

```
virtio0: local:105/vm-105-disk-1.qcow2,size=10G
```

Прирост скорости приятно удивил. Но на НЕКОТОРЫХ машинах скорость не изменилась:

```
hdparm -t /dev/vda 768 MB in  3.00 seconds = 255.58 MB/sec
```

и

```
hdparm -t /dev/sda 768 MB in  3.00 seconds = 260.58 MB/sec
```

что почти одинаково.

На тех же машинах, где все стало «красиво»:

```
hdparm -t /dev/vda 768 MB in  3.00 seconds = 760.58 MB/sec
```

Понимаю, что проблема в самой *ВМ*. Но пока не могу понять, почему *ВМ* как будто не воспринимает, что работает с *virtio*-драйвером. На машинах установлены *ubuntu server 12.04 LTS*.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: все виртуальные диски находятся на одном реальном накопителе?

Comment: Да. Все виртуальные диски находятся на одном реальном накопителе.

Comment: хм... Вот пока не увидел ваш вопрос - думал, что у меня все хорошо...
На одной инсталляции Proxmox-а(3.4-156) переход на virtio дал заметный прирост скорости. На другой (3.1-114) - вообще никакой разницы между scsi и virtio-дисками

Comment: А какой там формат виртуального тома? qcow2 или raw? Возможно это влияет. Еще, производительность qcow похоже деградирует со временем.

Comment: формат виртуального тома raw. Но от этого не сильно зависит скорость работы тома. Пробовал оба формата на тестовой ВМ. Проблема не в этом.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел на оффоруме следующий хинт:
Тип накопителя указать как scsi, а в options указать тип эмуляции scsi как virtio.
т.е. конфиг получится подобный:

```
bootdisk: scsi0
scsi0: local:105/vm-105-disk-1.qcow2,size=10G
scsihw: virtio-scsi-pci
```